# Какой плагин Wordpress использовать для такого вида расписания?

Tags: wordpress, плагин, wordpress-плагины, wp-plugin

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно на скриншоте, нужно чтобы:

а) были дни недели и время занятия для каждого дня недели

б) чтобы заказчику удобно было самому добавлять занятия в дни недели

в) расписание будет обновляться каждую неделю

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Для тех, у кого стоит такая же задача, нарыл плагин **Table Generator** реально легкий будет для заказчиков, свои css накидал и всем хорошо.

[плагин](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/table-generator/)